# Devise - possible to use controller test to test user NOT signed in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise, rspec-rails

I have a controller that depends on the user being authenticated. So it looks like this

```
class PlansController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    puts "here"
    if user_signed_in?
      puts "true"
    else
      puts "false"
    end
  end
end
```

My controller tests are working just fine when teh user IS signed in, i.e., when I'm writing something like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'devise'
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end

describe "create action" do
  before do
    @user = User.create(...)
    sign_in :user, @user
  end

  it "should puts here and then true" do
    post :create
    # => here
    # => true
  end
end
```

But I'd also like to test what happens in the `else` statement. Not sure how to do this, it fundamentally doesn't even put the `here`. Is it possible to test this? Or should I just leave and let Devise be?

```
describe "create action" do
  before do
    @user = User.create(...)
    # do not sign in user (note I have also tried to do a sign_in and then sign_out, same result)
  end

  it "should puts here and then true" do
    post :create
    # => nothing is put, not even the first here!
    # => no real "error" either, just a test failure
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `before_action :authenticate_user!` will immediately redirect you to the default sign-in page, if the user isn't signed in, skipping the `create` action altogether.

The `if user_signed_in?` statement is moot in this case, because the user will always be signed in when that code has the chance to run.

If plans can be created with or without an authenticated user, remove the `before_action` line.